# Where does Windows 10 store backups? Can backups delete other data?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, backup, windows-backup

I have 2 HDDs in my computer, `D:` (2TB) and `F:` (256GB). `F:` stores all my personal data which I want to back up to `D:`, just in case. Using the windows 10 backup, I specify that `F:` should be backed up to `D:`.

What irritates me is that even though I made a backup, I can't see it anywhere in `D:`. Are backups saved in some hidden location on the drive? Will they respect the files I already have in `D:` or could these potentially get overwritten?

Comment: Windows Backups are indeed hidden by default.  You should use `Backup and Restore (Windows 7)` client to view any backups that might exist. How much data Windows will use to backup your files can be configured.  However, I don't recommend using Windows Backup, the client virtually has no options.  If anything goes wrong, you are out of luck, and you might have a backup that inaccessible or unusable.

Comment: You assign the backup drive when you do the Windows 10 File History backup. Go to Start, Settings, Update, Backup. Then below "Add a Drive" select More Options . You can see Advanced Settings and Restore from current backup. This should help you find your backups and where they were from.  Also in the first backup screen is Restore from older backups. You can look there as well

Comment: Windows 7 restore points are stored in the System Volume Information folder. Assume the same for W10